How old was Rebecca when she married Isaac?
Is there clear evidence of how old was Rebecca when she married Isaac?
The different options from the Jews perspective is varied:

Some sources have 3 years old and sent with a wet nurse

Around 10 years

Around 12-14 years


Rebecca’s birth seems to have taken place after Isaac's sacrifice at Mount Moriah and was around the death of Abraham's wife Sarah.

I added "reference-request" as a tag to make explicit that you're looking for evidence outside the Bible, thus preventing the question from getting closed.  +1 to neutralize the negative votes.

@GratefulDisciple thank you much appreciated

The Biblical account in Genesis chapter 24 must surely be taken as evidence, even the best evidence, for the age of Rebekah: even though scripture does not tell us her precise age, there is more than enough evidence she could not possibly have been 3 years old:

And the damsel was very fair to look upon, a virgin, neither had any man known her: and she went down to the well, and filled her pitcher, and came up. (Genesis 24:16)

She is not called a little toddler; She is "fair to look upon".. not a suitable phrase for a 3 year old; very likely, she has been sent to get water for the household, at 3 years old? Alone? "Neither had any man known her".. why is this mentioned at all, if she had been just 3 years old?
Later she has the presence of mind to offer to water the ten camels after their long journey,.. and did it.. which was a major task for anyone, but not possible for a 3 year old.  (And would Abraham's servant have accepted the offer from a three year old, and then have watched a three year old water all the camels without lifting a finger to help?)
Many, if not all, of the arguments above apply also to a ten year old.
Where data outside the Bible significantly conflicts with the Bible data, this should be highlighted, the disagreement should be pointed out.  Extra-biblical claims should be weighed in the light of the Biblical data.
Anyone who examines rabbinic chronology will discover it is conflicting with itself and so is often unreliable.  An example is the interminable debates in the Talmud about the length of the Jubilee cycle, whether it was 49 years or 50 years.
It suits the agenda of some to justify their sexual desires and marriage practices by claiming Rebekah was just three years old.  From the Bible it is clear she was not, and we should make it clear also.
Finally, the idea Isaac waited three years before consummation of the marriage has no basis in scripture either:

And Isaac brought her into his mother Sarah's tent, and took Rebekah, and she became his wife; and he loved her; and Isaac was comforted after his mother's death. (Genesis 24:67)

Postscript
We have almost no age related data in the Bible concerning Rebeccah.  What can be calculated from Genesis is that Sarah, Isaac's mother, died three years before Isaac married Rebeccah.  This is probably the source of the three years which crops up in the Talmud as mentioned in the answer by Wyrsa.
We can gather this from:
Sarah was 10 year younger than Abraham, Gen 17v17.
Sarah died at 127 years old, Gen 23v1.
Abraham was 100, and Sarah 90, when Isaac was born, Gen 21v5.
So Sarah died 37 years (127-90) after Isaac was born, ie when Isaac was 37.
Isaac married when he was 40 years old, Gen 25v20.
So Isaac was comforted by marriage to Rebeccah three years after the death of his mother, Gen 24v67.  But anything could have happened in those three years: eg, it is quite possible Abraham did not send his servant to bring back a wife for Isaac until 1, 2 or 3 years after her death.
The most likely reading of scripture, I believe, is there was a delay of three years before Abraham sent his servant, gen 24.
Absolute Chronology
Finally, it can be calculated Isaac married Rebeccah in 2027t bc, and Sarah died 2030t. (The "t" suffix means the year beginning in Tishri, about September/October). This from the following:
The Seder Olam Rabbah says the New Year's Day, Rosh Hashanah, on the 10th Tishri, in Ezekiel 40v1, was the 17th Jubilee since entering the land. The author (in 1st or 2nd century AD) must have official records to examine, maintained by the priesthood over the centuries.  (See www.rcyoung.org).
The year of the Fall of Jerusalem and Temple was 587 bc, which was 588t, the year beginning tishri 588.
Ezekiel 40v1 was the 14th year after the city was smitten, ie 574t.
17 times 49 years of Jubilee cycle is 833 years. So Fall of the walls of Jericho was 1407t, in spring of 1406, and Exodus was 1447t, that is spring of 1446.
The above is confirmed by the date of 1447t gained from work of the Jesuit Priest, Valerius Coucke; and independently by the seventh day adventist, Edwin Thiele along with bible chronologist Rodger C. Young (see rcyoung.org). These all arrive at the date of the spring of 1446 for the Exodus.  In Biblical chronology, our Lord follows his own rule that "out of the mouths of two or three witnesses everything might be established" -  Matthew 18:16, Deuteronomy 22:25.
So following Thiele, Andrew Steinmann places the temple construction start date in the month Ziv of 967, which was 968t, ("From Abraham to Paul - a Biblical chronology", page 125).
479 years before that was the Exodus, 1 Kings 6:1. And 968t - 479 = 1447t.  The Exodus was in the spring of 1447t which was 1446.
Jacob went down to Egypt in year two of famine 430 years earlier, Exodus 12:40-41, 1877t, spring of 1876.
Jacob was 130 at that time, Gen 47:9, born 2007t.
Isaac was 60 when Jacob born, Gen 25:26. Isaac born 2067t.
Abraham was 100 when Isaac was born, Gen 21:5. Abraham born 2167t.
Sarah born 2157t, Gen 17:17, died 2030t, Gen 23:1.
Isaac married Rebeccah at 40, Gen 25:20, 2027t, probably about april/May 2026 bc.

fair points, it was a different time you could be seen as adults by age 10.  Have you taken into account  'Wyrsa' timelines & Gen 20:22 seems to imply Rebecca was born after Abraham came back from Mount Moriah and got news of her birth when Isaac was 37years old and he married at 40.  Note: The Talmud permits sex with 3 years 1 day old who would than become his wife.  does that have any bearing or should it be disregarded as people’s opinions?

The Talmud's age of consent, if true, and I would need the evidence to believe it, has no bearing.  Most Christians never read it. It has no bearing on what is from God.  Whenever I have read the Talmud it seems to have an enormous number of suffering opinions on almost every topic.  The Scriptures are from God, the Talmud simply isn't on the Christian radar.  Having said that, at times the Talmud can be helpful in gaining greater understanding of Scripture.  Its data needs to be weighed with care. To allow marriage at 3 years and 1 day, if we mean consummation, it is absurd, and cruel.

Suffering = differing, lol.  If it means simple betrothal, promising a daughter to someone's son, in an arranged marriage, it is irrelevant.. Arranged marriage, though maybe not the ideal, might be difficult to prove is contrary to scripture.

noted & Yes Talmud more of a historic ref.  A very small flavour of the Talmud.
Gittin 57a. Says Jesus is in hell, being boiled in "hot excrement."
Sanhedrin 58b. If a heathen (gentile) hits a Jew, the gentile must be killed.
Yebamoth 98a. All gentile children are animals.
Sanhedrin 54b. A Jew may have sex with a child as long as the child is less than nine years old.
Niddah 44b - MISHNAH. A GIRL OF THE AGE OF THREE YEARS AND ONE DAY MAY BE BETROTHED23  BY INTERCOURSE;
As to the Q - Gen 24:67  ‘…he took Rebekah and she became his wife….’

Right then, I'm eastern Orthodox, but this requires actual research so...
Rebecca, Rebekah, "Righteous Rebecca"

The Jewish virtual library says:

The biblical matriarch Rebekah (Heb. רִבְקָה) was the wife of Isaac and the mother of Jacob. She was the daughter of Bethuel, and granddaughter of Nahor, a brother of Abraham (Gen. 22:23; 24:15, 24, 47). Rebekah is also described as the sister of Laban (24:29, 50; 25:20). When Abraham sought a wife for his son, he sent his servant to his homeland, Aram-Naharaim, for he wanted to avoid marriage with the Canaanites. The episode is described in detail in Genesis 24, which makes clear the providential nature of the union of Isaac with Rebekah (verses 7, 14, 27, 48, 50).
When Abraham wanted to find a wife for Isaac, he sent his servant to his hometown of Aram-Naharaim. The servant came to a spring and prayed to God. He proposed a sign — the first woman to give water to both him and his camels would be the one who would be right for Isaac. Immediately, Rebekah approached him, and when he asked for a drink, she ran to the spring and brought water for both him and his camels. The servant went with Rebekah to her house, where he received permission from her father and her brother,  Laban, to take Rebekah to Canaan as a wife for Isaac. Isaac married Rebekah when he was 40 years old (25:20); Rebekah’s age is not recorded. According to Genesis, he was only comforted after his mother’s death when he married Rebekah and took her into his mother’s tent.



The verse (Gen. 25:26) explicitly records Isaac’s age at the birth of his two sons to be 60 years old. In Gen.25:20 we learn that he married Rebecca at age 40. Therefore, if, as much of the rabbinic chronology indicates, she was 3 at the time of marriage she would have given birth, as you suggested, at age 23. However, there are opinions that she was older (for example Ibn Ezra) at the time of her marriage to Isaac. (R' Daniel Fleksher)


The Ibn Ezra (Gen. 24:59) explains that when Rebecca is sent out with her “nurse”, this is referring to the woman who used to be her nurse long before, implying that she has grown significantly since then. On the other hand, I have a three year old son who is of average size and, at least physically, would be capable of carrying significant amounts of water (approx. 3 liters at a time) until the job was done. Whether he would think to do that on his own is a different story. (A published follow up comment at Ibid)


From Sefaria.org...

Rashi’s comment on this apparently historically irrelevant detail, is that the Torah informed us that Yitzchok, after marrying Rivkah, waited for three years until she was old enough to engage in intercourse and become pregnant. (14 years old) [In his commentary on Genesis 24,16, item 91 Rabbi Kasher in his Torah Shleymah, deals at length with the conflicting opinions about Rivkah’s age at marriage.


I would factor in some travel time as well... But ultimately we don't know the exact age. Which is the honest answer here. There are many traditions involved here, but if they existed before the law did is another matter.

Where are the two quoted paragraphs in the middle section from?

Thank you it’s a very helpful indication - I would presume the 3-year wait might have been for puberty around 10-year age - so could have possible married around 6/7 years.

@RayButterworth "Jewishanswers.org" https://www.jewishanswers.org/index.php?p=1870 ; You just put in Rebecca in the search bar on the website and there are only 3 articles one of which is "age of isaac and rebecca"

@Wyrsa says "You just put in Rebecca in the search bar on the website" — But we shouldn't have to. The question itself should contain the appropriate citation. Ditto for the third quotation.

@RayButterworth fair point... good luck.

The precise age is not given, however, the description of Rebecca given certainly means she was at least in her mid-teens, if not older.
Genesis 24:16 And the damsel was very fair to look upon, a virgin, neither had any man known her: and she went down to the well, and filled her pitcher, and came up.
This is the description the the Bible gives about Rebecca. Honestly, it cannot be used to describe a young child (prepubescent). It cannot be used to describe a child under age 12.
The Bible never gives an age. Therefore, we cannot be dogmatic on such matters. But given the description of Rebecca when she married Isaac, she was probably somewhere between ages 15-34 years old.
There is no precise age, but my best guess might be her early 20s. Given that she was of childbearing age, however, and given that this took place well after the Flood (following the Flood, lifespans generally do not exceed 100 years), I would assume that Rebecca was in her 20s.

The age of "in her 20s" is possible, but maybe, even probably, rather too old.  I think I follow the usual view when I think of the mid teens, about 14 to 17.  Some would go a touch younger, but the phrase "no man had known her" suggests to me she had finished puberty a year or two at least already.

There is a lot of modern propaganda against marrying in teens, even growing propaganda not to marry at all.  This comes from the United Nation bodies, such as the UN Population Fund, UNICEF, other assoc. bodies such as WEF, other groups such as Rockerfeller Foundation, IPPF, etc.  See "The War Against Population" by Jacqueline Kasun.

I agree, and the modern propaganda to not get married in your teens or not to get married at all comes from groups with a population control agenda such as the ones that you mentioned. The reason why the UN Population Fund and other organizations campaign against young parenthood is because they want population control. This is another reason why the myth of the immature Teen Brain (under-25s) is promoted; it helps control population growth. I agree that perhaps Rebecca was probably in her mid-teens but probably not older than early 20s.

The fact of the matter is that contrary to popular belief, marrying after 25 doesn't assure anything. Men who get married before age 20 have a lower divorce rate than men marrying in their upper 20s.
https://www.mckinleyirvin.com/family-law-blog/2012/october/32-shocking-divorce-statistics/

Having a higher divorce rate is a successful outcome for the population control lobby.  So its another reason for promoting it. Our bad is their good, and our good is their bad.  I'm delighted you are informed on these issues.  How come?

The reason why I am informed on such issue is because I have done my research; I have had good friends over the years who have informed me on such matters. The higher divorce rates are beneficial for the population control lobby.
I have done my research because just a few years ago, I read up some nonsense promoted by the mainstream media that brains supposedly are immature until 25. I knew right then and there that it was ridiculous; this lead me to read writings by Dr. Robert Epstein (Harvard Psychologist) who exposed the infantilization of young people in modern societies.

And through more research and friends who educated me, I learned that the elites want population control and one good method is discouraging marriage/parenthood until age 25, if not later.
It was through the PLANDEMIC that I read up population control agendas by Gates, Rockefellers, the UN, and other elites. I have been well-informed about this. What pushed me to do research? It was around age 20-21 when I read about the ridiculous myth of brains supposedly not maturing until 25, and I ended up reading Robert Epstein's books debunking the myth of adolescence.
